# Conditional Unary in JS inconsistent response

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why does this code:

```
var score = 0;
score = ("H".charCodeAt(0) === "H".charCodeAt(0)) ? score += 1 : score;
console.log("score should be one here and it is = " + score);
```

while this below does not seem to work:

```
var score = 0;
score = ("H".charCodeAt(0) === "H".charCodeAt(0)) ? score ++ : score;
console.log("score should be one here but its (zero) = " + score);
```

Looks technically the same to me?  Am using nodejs to run this.

Comment: Neither code looks good. Assign to score *only once* for clear code - don't assign inside the conditional *and also* as the result of the conditional. `score = (condition) ? score + 1 : score` or even `if (condition) score++`

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance.  Apologies for missing that earlier answer.